# Connect Titanium Studio to remote git repository

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-mobile

I'm getting started with Titanium Studio to build mobile apps. I'm using Beanstalkapp (or any other remote git/svn repository) for version control.

I can't find a way to connect a new project to the remote repository from within titanium studio.

I can:
1 - create a new mobile project and start a new local git repository
2 - import an empty project from the remote git repository

When using 1 I don't know how to commit to a remote repository.
When using 2 I don't know how to add a mobile project, I always get "a project with the same name already exists within the workspace"

Any tips on how to set this up conveniently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the file menu in Ti Studio, choose Import, Then choose Git Repository as New Project, click next, enter your beanstalk URI and click finish.

I have not tried this with beanstalk, but it works flawlessly with Github.com

Once you have set up the project, access the context menu of the project in the project explorer (ctrl-click) and your git commands will be accessible from the Team menu